# How to pass down props / all of the values of an object for a dynamic component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I have a v-for loop, which loops through objects of a fetched list of todos. The looped objects are passed to a child component, which holds an individual todo. The problem is that, when inspecting with vue devtools, only one value of the single Todo is accessed - todo. Originally a todo should have 3 values: id, completion and todo, but when passing it down, only todo value is accessed.Any recommendations?

**main component, which holds the v-for loop**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <CreateTodo />
    <hr />

    <div class="TodoContainer">
      <div v-for="todo in todos" v-bind:key="todo.id" class="TodoComponent">
        <SingleTodo v-bind="todo" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <hr />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import CreateTodo from "./CreateTodo";
import SingleTodo from "./SingleTodo";
import { ref, onMounted } from "vue";

//
export default {
  components: {
    CreateTodo,
    SingleTodo,
  },

  setup() {
    const API_URL = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/todo-list/";
    const todos = ref([]);

    async function getTodos() {
      const response = await fetch(API_URL);
      const json = await response.json();
      todos.value = json;
    }

    onMounted(() => {
      getTodos();
    });

    return {
      todos,
      getTodos,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

**single component**

```
<template>
  <div class="TodoComponent">
    <router-link :to="`/rest-todo/${todo.id}`" class="TodoValue">
      id: {{ todo.id }}
    </router-link>
    <div
      class="TodoValue"
      :class="{
        completeTrue: todo.completion == true,
        completeFalse: todo.completion == false,
      }"
    >
      {{ todo }}{{ completion  }}
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ["todo"],
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, kind of. When you bind an todo in the v-for loop, you have to define each passed down value in the child component props in order to access it. Answer below

**single component**

```
<script>
export default {
  props: ["todo", 'completion', 'id'],
};
</script>
```

Comment: This is not necessarily the right answer, because defining an object-typed prop is definitely possible, too.